# Use SyntheticaBlackEye with java 7

Tags: java-7, look-and-feel, uimanager, synthetica

I want to use the look and feel named SyntheticaBlackEye with my java application, so I downloaded the jar files of the look and feel from [here](http://www.jyloo.com/synthetica/themes/) then I put the jar file inside the library folder of my project then I set the look and feel like as follows:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel());
```

And I added that import:

```
import de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel;
```

The problem is that the compiler refused and told me that `no suitable method found for setLookAndFeel(de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel)`

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel");
```

instead of:

```
setLookAndFeel(de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel);
```

inside `try catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download the required Jar from [This is the Synthetica main Jar](http://jyloo.com/synthetica/download/) note that you have to register and there is **Evaluation** and **Licensees** links (choose whatever suites your project).

Now you have to download the theme Jar from many here [Themes for Synthetica](http://jyloo.com/synthetica/themes/%3Bjsessionid%3D1dbbc119692c36023becab78c60d).

Add the two Jar files to your project classpath then do this:

```
import de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaPlainLookAndFeel;

try {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaPlainLookAndFeel());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```